# Can only instantiate this object with a string(Laravel)?

Tags: laravel

I get this error when I call route.
I give a route Like:

```
<a href="{{ route('billing', ['plan' => $plan[0]->id]) }}">
   <button style="padding:15px 25px;border:none;color:#007F5F;font-weight:700;font-size:20px;border-         radius:10px;">Choose Plan</button>
</a>
```

but When I click on link I get this error : [Laravel Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nJjF.png)

This is my Route:

```
    if (Util::registerPackageRoute('billing.process', $manualRoutes)) {
        Route::get(
            '/billing/process/{plan?}',
            BillingController::class.'@process'
        )
        ->middleware(['verify.shopify'])
        ->where('plan', '^([0-9]+|)$')
        ->name(Util::getShopifyConfig('route_names.billing.process'));
    }
```

I can't understand this error please help me to solve this error.

Comment: wait, you can use `if` in the `web.php`? have you checked with `php artisan route:list` and see if your routes are actually loaded? I can't find any references for `Util::registerPackageRoute` in the official docs, where is this thing came from?

Comment: this is shopify manual routes, sir Bagus Tesa.

Comment: sorry, i do use laravel but i'm not familiar with shopify. is this shopify the [new](https://github.com/Kyon147/laravel-shopify) one or [old](https://github.com/gnikyt/laravel-shopify) one? also, is `php artisan route:list` still works?

Comment: if its the old (no longer supported shopify), see [this issue](https://github.com/gnikyt/laravel-shopify/issues/872). use `Url::tokeRoute` instead of laravel's `route`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my error by adding `shop` parameter on the route :

My route Now :

```
<a href="{{ route('billing', ['plan' => 2, 'shop' => Auth::user()->name]) }}">
  <button style="padding:15px 25px;border:none;color:#007F5F;font- 
    weight:700;font-size:20px;border-radius:10px;">Choose Plan</button>
</a>
```

This route works fine:

Check out relevant issue: https://github.com/gnikyt/laravel-shopify/issues/872